# Pentaho Initialization Exception

Tags: quartz-scheduler, pentaho

When I am trying to start my `Pentaho BI` server, I received a couple of errors. I understand that this cannot start the `QuartZ` database, but could I have some help resolving the following issue?

**Pentaho user console**

> The following errors were detected.
>
> One or more system listeners failed. These are set in the systemListeners.xml.
>
> PentahoSystem.ERROR_0014 - Error while trying to execute startup
>   sequence for org.pentaho.platform.scheduler.QuartzSystemListener
>
> Please see the server console for more details on each error detected.

**Below is the log file**

> 10:13:55,832 WARN  [PackageManager] Unresolved dependency for package:
>   org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.extensions.datasources.cda.CdaModule
>   10:13:55,857 WARN  [PackageSorter] A dependent module was not found in the list of known modules.
>   10:13:58,963 ERROR [Logger] misc-org.pentaho.platform.scheduler.QuartzSystemListener: QuartzSystemListener.ERROR_0001 - > Scheduler was not properly initialized at startup
>   org.quartz.SchedulerConfigException: Failure occured during job recovery. [See nested exception: org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Failed to obtain DB connection from data source 'myDS': java.sql.SQLException: Could not retrieve datasource via JNDI url 'java:comp/env/jdbc/Quartz' org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user 'pentaho_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)) [See nested exception: java.sql.SQLException: Could not retrieve datasource via JNDI url 'java:comp/env/jdbc/Quartz' org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user 'pentaho_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES))]]
>     at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.initialize(JobStoreSupport.java:493)
>     at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX.initialize(JobStoreTX.java:68)
>     at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.instantiate(StdSchedulerFactory.java:1010)
>     at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.getScheduler(StdSchedulerFactory.java:1152)
>     at org.pentaho.platform.scheduler.QuartzSystemListener.startup(QuartzSystemListener.java:112)
>     at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.notifySystemListenersOfStartup(PentahoSystem.java:342)
>     at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.notifySystemListenersOfStartup(PentahoSystem.java:324)
>     at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.init(PentahoSystem.java:291)
>     at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.init(PentahoSystem.java:208)
>     at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.context.SolutionContextListener.contextInitialized(SolutionContextListener.java:137)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4135)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4630)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:546)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:637)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:563)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:498)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1277)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:321)
>     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
>   * Nested Exception (Underlying Cause) ---------------
>   org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Failed to obtain DB connection from data source 'myDS': java.sql.SQLException: Could not retrieve datasource via JNDI url 'java:comp/env/jdbc/Quartz' org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user 'pentaho_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)) [See nested exception: java.sql.SQLException: Could not retrieve datasource via JNDI url 'java:comp/env/jdbc/Quartz' org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user 'pentaho_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES))]
>     at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.getConnection(JobStoreSupport.java:575)
>     at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX.cleanVolatileTriggerAndJobs(JobStoreTX.java:109)
>     at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.initialize(JobStoreSupport.java:491)
>     at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX.initialize(JobStoreTX.java:68)
>     at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.instantiate(StdSchedulerFactory.java:1010)
>     at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.getScheduler(StdSchedulerFactory.java:1152)
>     at org.pentaho.platform.scheduler.QuartzSystemListener.startup(QuartzSystemListener.java:112)
>     at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.notifySystemListenersOfStartup(PentahoSystem.java:342)
>     at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.notifySystemListenersOfStartup(PentahoSystem.java:324)
>     at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.init(PentahoSystem.java:291)
>     at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.init(PentahoSystem.java:208)
>     at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.context.SolutionContextListener.contextInitialized(SolutionContextListener.java:137)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4135)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4630)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:546)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:637)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:563)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:498)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1277)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:321)
>     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
>   * Nested Exception (Underlying Cause) ---------------
>   java.sql.SQLException: Could not retrieve datasource via JNDI url 'java:comp/env/jdbc/Quartz' org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user 'pentaho_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES))
>     at org.quartz.utils.JNDIConnectionProvider.getConnection(JNDIConnectionProvider.java:166)
>     at org.quartz.utils.DBConnectionManager.getConnection(DBConnectionManager.java:111)
>     at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.getConnection(JobStoreSupport.java:553)
>     at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX.cleanVolatileTriggerAndJobs(JobStoreTX.java:109)
>     at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.initialize(JobStoreSupport.java:491)
>     at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX.initialize(JobStoreTX.java:68)
>     at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.instantiate(StdSchedulerFactory.java:1010)
>     at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.getScheduler(StdSchedulerFactory.java:1152)
>     at org.pentaho.platform.scheduler.QuartzSystemListener.startup(QuartzSystemListener.java:112)
>     at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.notifySystemListenersOfStartup(PentahoSystem.java:342)
>     at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.notifySystemListenersOfStartup(PentahoSystem.java:324)
>     at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.init(PentahoSystem.java:291)
>     at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.init(PentahoSystem.java:208)
>     at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.context.SolutionContextListener.contextInitialized(SolutionContextListener.java:137)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4135)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4630)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:546)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:637)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:563)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:498)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1277)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:321)
>     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
>   10:13:58,967 ERROR [Logger] Error: Pentaho
>   10:13:58,967 ERROR [Logger] misc-org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem: PentahoSystem.ERROR_0014 - Error while trying to execute startup sequence for org.pentaho.platform.scheduler.QuartzSystemListener
>   org.pentaho.platform.api.engine.PentahoSystemException: PentahoSystem.ERROR_0014 - Error while trying to execute startup sequence for org.pentaho.platform.scheduler.QuartzSystemListener
>     at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.notifySystemListenersOfStartup(PentahoSystem.java:350)
>     at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.notifySystemListenersOfStartup(PentahoSystem.java:324)
>     at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.init(PentahoSystem.java:291)
>     at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.init(PentahoSystem.java:208)
>     at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.context.SolutionContextListener.contextInitialized(SolutionContextListener.java:137)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4135)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4630)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:546)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:637)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:563)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:498)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1277)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:321)
>     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
>   Caused by: org.pentaho.platform.api.engine.PentahoSystemException: PentahoSystem.ERROR_0014 - Error while trying to execute startup sequence for org.pentaho.platform.scheduler.QuartzSystemListener
>     at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.notifySystemListenersOfStartup(PentahoSystem.java:343)
>     ... 28 more
>   10:13:58,968 ERROR [Logger] Error end:

Comment: When i loged in to PAC , i got following error 

"The entity "nbsp" was referenced, but not declared."

when i refresh my BI server through admin console i get following error , 

"Error while trying to execute startup sequence for org.pentaho.platform.scheduler.QuartzSystemListener</td></tr> "

Comment: Could you please post code where the error is?

Comment: do want me to post code in start-pentaho file

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here with Pentaho 6.1 on windows running as service. When runnning not as service it worked.

Solution:
It's a bug since 5.2.
http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/BISERVER-12183

Solution is to set the Startup - Working Path with tomcat8w.exe //ES// correctly. Instead of biserver-ce\tomcat it should be biserver-ce\tomcat\bin.

Due to the wrong path, pentaho creates a new empty HSQLDB which doesn't have the user "pentaho_user". 
Additionally the pentaho.log resides in the wrong directory. In biserver-ce\log instead of in biserver-ce\tomcat\log. This is fixed by changing th Working Path, too.

Comment: Worked exactly as described thanks - I just changed the 'Startup - Working Path' field to tomcat\bin

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below steps to over these problem :

1) Stop BI server
2) Flushed the Privileges of QuartZ database , created new user and password for QuartZ database and included new credentials at context.xml under `/biserver-ce/tomcat/webapps/pentaho/META-INF/` folder.
3) Re-start  BI server
4) Try accessing your PUC.