# Unable to to start Pentaho BI Server on Windows environment

Tags: java, windows, pentaho

I'm new to Pentaho BI Server. I've downloaded the community edition of Pentaho BI Server (biserver-ce-6.0.1.0-386), and I'm trying to run it on a Windows 10 (x64) machine. I've set "PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME" environmental path variable as suggested in http://akbarahmed.com/2012/05/12/install-pentaho-bi-server-4-5-on-windows-7-x64/ *(this is for an older version of BI Server but I assume that the same method would be applicable here)*.

When I'm running start-pentaho.bat, this is the output I'm getting:

```
G:\Pentaho\biserver-ce-6.0.1.0-386\biserver-ce>start-pentaho.bat
DEBUG: Using PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME
DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_79
DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "G:\Pentaho\biserver-ce-6.0.1.0-386\biserver-ce\tomcat"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "G:\Pentaho\biserver-ce-6.0.1.0-386\biserver-ce\tomcat"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "G:\Pentaho\biserver-ce-6.0.1.0-386\biserver-ce\tomcat\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_79"
Using CLASSPATH:       "G:\Pentaho\biserver-ce-6.0.1.0-386\biserver-ce\tomcat\bin\bootstrap.jar;G:\Pentaho\biserver-ce-6.0.1.0-386\biserver-ce\tomcat\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
```

A command prompt window briefly appears and then disappears. I am not getting any error messages thereafter, but if I visit http://localhost:8080, it seems that no server is listening on port 8080.

When I try to stop BI Server, this is what I'm getting:

```
G:\Pentaho\biserver-ce-6.0.1.0-386\biserver-ce>stop-pentaho.bat
DEBUG: Using PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME
DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_79
DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "G:\Pentaho\biserver-ce-6.0.1.0-386\biserver-ce\tomcat"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "G:\Pentaho\biserver-ce-6.0.1.0-386\biserver-ce\tomcat"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "G:\Pentaho\biserver-ce-6.0.1.0-386\biserver-ce\tomcat\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_79"
Using CLASSPATH:       "G:\Pentaho\biserver-ce-6.0.1.0-386\biserver-ce\tomcat\bin\bootstrap.jar;G:\Pentaho\biserver-ce-6.0.1.0-386\biserver-ce\tomcat\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
13-Mar-2016 03:06:22.590 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stopServer Could not contact localhost:8005. Tomcat may not be running.
13-Mar-2016 03:06:22.605 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stopServer Catalina.stop:
 java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stopServer(Catalina.java:450)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.stopServer(Bootstrap.java:400)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:487)
```

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong and how to rectify the issue.

Comment: Your logs mention localhost:8005. Check that your web.xml is properly configured to bind to the port you want to use; and also that the port is available when pentaho starts.

Comment: @nsousa I verified that the port binding was mentioned in `server.xml` file, and that the port is free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED:** I found out that the issue was due to an attempt to use a 32-bit Java. I came across this message,

```
WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.init The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library failed to load. The error reported was [G:\Pentaho\biserver-ce-6.0.1.0-386\biserver-ce\tomcat\bin\tcnative-1.dll: Can't load AMD 64-bit .dll on a IA 32-bit platform]
```

[Screenshot of Tomcat Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNpes.png)

I set the PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME environmental variable to point to a 64-bit JDK installed on my system, and now, Pentaho BI Server starts up as expected.

Answer (score 3):

I got the very same behavior trying to start Pentaho BI server community edition version 5.3/JRE7 on AMD Athlon/Windows 10 Home (32-bit). The solution that worked for me was to start Tomcat as a Windows service, as follows:

*(Note: The notes below assume that Pentaho BI Server was installed in C:\Pentaho)*

1. Edit the system environment variables to include the following:

   ```
   PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME  = C:\Program Files\Java\jre7
   ```
2. If another application is using port 8080, edit the *C:\Pentaho \biserver-ce\tomcat\conf\server.xml* file to replace every occurrence of port 8080 with a new port number, e.g. 8081.
3. Using an Administrator Command Prompt, navigate to *C:\Pentaho\biserver-ce\tomcat\bin* and run the command:

   ```
   service.bat install
   ```

(see https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html for further details).

4. At the same Administrator Command Prompt, run

   ```
   tomcat6w.exe
   ```

to launch an application that allows you to startup and shutdown the service, and modify the service settings. The graphical user interface of the application opens.

5. In the application, modify the Tomcat settings as follows:

   (a) Under the “Logging” tab, ensure that the logs sub-directory is under the tomcat directory -e.g.:

   ```
    C:\Pentaho\biserver-ce\tomcat\logs
   ```

   (b) Under the “Java” tab, append the following parameters under the existing lines in the “Java Options” text box (open *C:\Pentaho\biserver-ce\start-pentaho.bat* with a text editor and see the 32-bit and 64-bit processor settings – the ones below are for 32-bit processors):

   ```
   -Xms256m
   -Xmx768m
   -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
   -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000
   -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000
   ```

   (c) Under the “Startup” tab, ensure that the value in the “Working Path” text box points to the *\tomcat\bin* sub-directory - e.g.:

   ```
   C:\Pentaho\biserver-ce\tomcat\bin
   ```

(see  solution [Pentaho Initialization Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17183331/pentaho-initialization-exception) offered by Shivan on December 7, 2016 at for further details).

6. Under the “General” tab, click the “Start” button to startup Pentaho BI Server.
7. Using your web browser, launch the Pentaho BI server using the link  http://localhost:8081/. **The Pentaho login screen should appear at this point - it did for me.**
8. After using Pentaho, you gracefully shutdown the Tomcat service by clicking on the “Stop” button.